# How does pagination affect rate limit

Tags: stocktwits

I am looking at http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/parameters and am wondering if anyone has used pagination before.

The doc says there is a limit of 800 messages, how does that interact with the request limit? Could I in theory query 200 different stock tickers every hour and get back (up to) 800 messages?

If so that sounds like a great way to get around the 30 message limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is unclear on this and we are rolling out new documentation that explains this more clearly.

Every stream request will have a default and max limit of 30 messages per response, regardless of whether the cursor params are present or not. So you could query 200 different stock streams every hour and get up to 6,000 messages or 12,000 if sending your access token along with the request. 200 request per hour for non authenticated requests and 400 for authenticated requests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification